# How to translate "连环夺宝", the name of a game from China LotSynergy?

Tags: translation

"连环夺宝" is a popular game operated by China Welfare Lottery.
It can be seen in this video: http://v.youku.com/v_show/id_XMjkyNDczNDI4.html .

I've heard it referred to as "Precious Stones" in English, but this doesn't seem correct.

Google Translate suggests "Indiana" for "夺宝", which I assume is via the movie Raiders Of The Lost Ark, and the concept is about hunting, or raiding, or acquisition?

"连环" presumably refers to sequences of symbols, or chains, or connections?

What would be an appropriate English translation of the game name?

Comment: How about `Serial Treasure Hunt`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"夺宝" should be translated separately.
"夺" means win / capture.
"宝" means treasure.
"连环" means again and again here. "连环" can also mean chain but not applicable here. 
All together is "Win the treasure again and again".

Google translate suggests that "夺宝" = "Indiana" which is wrong. 
I believe it's because "Indiana Jones" was translated into "夺宝奇兵" in China which the translated name is not a direct translation.